# How to avoid floating action button from hiding

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a fab anchored to collapsing toolbar and when toolbar collapses, fab automatically hides and I want it to stop hiding

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|start"/>
```

I just want fab's moving animation not hiding

Comment: how about not adding app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|start"

Comment: removing anchor stops animation

Comment: isnt that what you want?

Comment: thanks when i scroll the page, fab scrolls too then hides i want to stop it from hiding

Answer (score 0):

I used floating navigation view library and it did the job

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid floating action button from hiding
by setting elevation

```
    app:elevation="6dp"
```